# android 8.0 and 8.1 firebase runtime exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-8.0-oreo

/*  I tried Many Ways but it didnt solve my problem can any one help me out?  */

thanks advance

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3705)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1979)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: at
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:644)
at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService (Unknown Source:23)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzj (Unknown Source:11)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzb (Unknown Source:72)
at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.onReceive (Unknown Source:25)
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException:at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3705)at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (Unknown Source)at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1979)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)

Comment: Add logcat of error also share code snippet which causes problem. Please add more details or your question will get downvoted.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: at 
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService (ContextWrapper.java:644)
  at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService (Unknown Source:23) at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzj (Unknown Source:11)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.zzb (Unknown Source:72)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver.onReceive (Unknown Source:25)

Comment: add in main question and not in comments

Comment: i tried its not getting added so i added in coments

Comment: have you added wakelock permission like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Yes, i have added in manifest

Comment: i m still facing issue after ading this line <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> help me out in this?